# How can I put some space around td text?

Tags: css

I have a demo  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CEFLU/1/) how can I put some space around the texts in side the table? also why not the css class is working in the demo?

css

```
.recomendationsTable{
width:100%;overflow:hidden;
}
.recomendationsTable tr{
border:#2F5882 1px solid;
} 
.recomendationsTable tr th{
color :#ffffff;
background-color: #93A8BF;
}
.recomendationsTable tr .odd{
color :#FFFFFF;
background-color: #8EA4BB;
border:#2F5882 1px solid;
}
.recomendationsTable tr .even{
color :#2F5882;
background-color: #EDF1F5;
border:#2F5882 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: use **cellpadding** attrribute inside the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it didn't work was because of the spaces between the class and the element.

```
.recomendationsTable {
    width:100%;overflow:hidden;
}

.recomendationsTable tr {
    border:#2F5882 1px solid;
}

.recomendationsTable tr th {
    color :#ffffff;
    background-color: #93A8BF;
}

.recomendationsTable tr.odd {
    color :#FFFFFF;
    background-color: #8EA4BB;
    border:#2F5882 1px solid;
}

.recomendationsTable tr.even {
    color :#2F5882;
    background-color: #EDF1F5;
    border:#2F5882 1px solid;
}
```

Additionally, to add space you need to add the following (first value vertical padding, second horizontal - this example gives 10px on both sides):

```
.recomendationsTable tr td {
    padding: 0 10px;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add some padding:

```
td {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

As far as the `even` and `odd` rows not showing up, just remove the space between `tr .even` and `tr .odd`. With the space, the CSS selector is looking for a descendant with the `even` or `odd` class. Without the space, you're telling it to look for a `tr` with an `even` or `odd` class attached to it.

On another note, it might be better to generate your table programmatically instead of through HTML strings; it's a little easier to maintain:

```
var $table = jQuery("<table></table>").attr("class", "recommendationsTable");

var $tr = jQuery("<tr></tr>");
$tr.append(jQuery("<th></th>".attr("align", "left").text("Recommendation(s)"));
$table.append($tr);

$tr = jQuery("<tr></tr>").attr("class", "even");
$tr.append(jQuery("<td></td>").text(ruleactionresult1));
$table.append($tr);

...
```

An even better way would be to put this into a loop:

```
var rules = ["bbbbb", "aaaa"];
var classes = ["even", "odd"];
var i = 0;

var $table = jQuery("<table></table>").attr("class", "recommendationsTable");

var $tr = jQuery("<tr></tr>");
$tr.append(jQuery("<th></th>".attr("align", "left").text("Recommendation(s)"));
$table.append($tr);

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $tr = jQuery("<tr></tr>").attr("class", class[i % 2]);
    $tr.append(jQuery("<td></td>").text(rules[i % 2]));
    $table.append($tr);
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CEFLU/12/).

Answer (score 1):

**why not the css class is working in the demo ?**

You should remove the space between tr and .odd, tr and .even

**I have a demo here how can I put some space around the texts in side the table?**

Use Td padding see answers above

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
  tr.even & tr.odd (joined)
  means tr with the evenodd class applied
  if there is a space, it means an element within the tr element
*/
.recomendationsTable tr.odd {
    color :#FFFFFF;
    background-color: #8EA4BB;
    border:#2F5882 1px solid;
}
.recomendationsTable tr.even {
    color :#2F5882;
    background-color: #EDF1F5;
    border:#2F5882 1px solid;
}

/* Also, add some padding between the cell's border and the text */
.recomendationsTable tr th,
.recomendationsTable tr td {
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Demo can be [found here](http://jsfiddle.net/CEFLU/8/)

Comment: And, as others have mentioned already, it's better to use jQuery to [build your table](http://jsfiddle.net/atQY8/1/) rather than inserting HTML.

Answer (score 1):

in one shot add `cellpadding` to the  created `table` as attribute
`or` if you want to play with classes set new definition in your css to the td also i.e. `.recomendationsTable td { padding:'what ever you want';}`

Answer (score 0):

Put a `DIV` in the cell, surrounding the text and give the `DIV` some padding.

or:

```
table tr td, table tr th { padding: 5px; }
```